# Ошибка «Извините, что-то пошло не так». при авторизации через facebook

Tags: php, laravel, api, facebook

Я реализовал авторизацию через facebook с помощью laravel. Когда я нахожусь на сайте и нажимаю кнопку авторизации через фейсбук, то происходит редирект на страницу с ошибкой "Извините, что-то пошло не так. Мы работаем над тем, чтобы исправить это, как только сможем".
Уже почти все потратил, так и не нашел решения этой проблемы.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

URL, где находится ошибка

https://www.facebook.com/v3.3/dialog/oauth?client_id=2040703196275670&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fgrowexspeak.space%2Ffacebook%2Fcallback&scope=email&response_type=code

Я оставляю код авторизации через facebook, сделанный через Laravel.

FacebookController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite;

class FaceBookController extends Controller
{
    public function loginUsingFacebook()
    {
       $facebook_user = Socialite::driver('facebook')->stateless()->redirect();

       return $facebook_user;
    }
     public function callbackFromFacebook()
     {
      try {
           $user = Socialite::driver('facebook')->stateless()->user();

           $saveUser = User::updateOrCreate([
               'facebook_id' => $user->getId(),
           ],[
               'name' => $user->getName(),
               'email' => $user->getEmail(),
               'password' => Hash::make($user->getName().'@'.$user->getId())
                ]);

           Auth::loginUsingId($saveUser->id);

           return redirect()->route('home');
           } catch (\Throwable $th) {
              throw $th;
           }
       }

}
```

config/services.php

```
facebook' => [
        'client_id' => '####', //USE FROM FACEBOOK DEVELOPER ACCOUNT
        'client_secret' => '####', //USE FROM FACEBOOK DEVELOPER ACCOUNT
        'redirect' => 'https://growexspeak.space/facebook/callback'
    ],
```

Web.php

```
  Route::prefix('facebook')->name('facebook.')->group( function(){
        Route::get('auth', [FaceBookController::class, 'loginUsingFacebook'])->name('login');
        Route::get('callback', [FaceBookController::class, 'callbackFromFacebook'])->name('callback');
    });
```

App.php

```
'providers' => [
        Laravel\Socialite\SocialiteServiceProvider::class,

        
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Class Aliases
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This array of class aliases will be registered when this application
    | is started. However, feel free to register as many as you wish as
    | the aliases are "lazy" loaded so they don't hinder performance.
    |
    */

    'aliases' => Facade::defaultAliases()->merge([
        // 'ExampleClass' => App\Example\ExampleClass::class,
        'Socialite' => Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite::class,

    ])->toArray(),
```

auth.blade.php

```
 <a href="{{ route('facebook.login') }}" class="btn btn-facebook btn-user btn-block">
   <i class="fab fa-facebook-f fa-fw"></i>
   Login with Facebook
</a>
```

Until I know the solution